# SQL job with schedule not working

Tags: sql-server, jobs

I need to create a job with schedule in SQL.
I created, but it not works at all. Maybe I'm missing something from tutorials, I don't know.

In this first image are the General settings of my job
[image]

In this image you can see the sql that I need to run on my DB. 
[image]

In this picture you can see the schedule: I schedule it to run on every day at 12 o' clock.

I tried to put an earlier hour to see if it affects to DB, meaning if the query runs, but the table is not updated.
When I click at Start Jobs I get the following error:
[image]

Can you please advise what can be wrong in these settings?
Thanks!

[image]

The SQLServer Agent is running:
[image]

and I keep getting the error when I right click on the job and press Start job at step:
[image]

Comment: Click on the link in the error-window and you'll see why it's failing.

Comment: I get: SQL Server Agent is not currently running so it cannot be notified of this action

Comment: @Orsi right click the SQL Server Agent icon in the Object Explorer tab and select "Start". Then you should be fine..

Comment: @Orsi Additionally you should set the start-type of "SQL Server Agent"-Service to "Automatic". Otherwise it will be failing again after a server reboot.

Comment: If I right click on SQL Server Agent on Object Explorer, the buttons: Start, Stop and Restart are disabled

Comment: @Orsi please [have a look how to start SQL Server Agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/start-stop-or-pause-the-sql-server-agent-service).

Comment: You probably don't have enough access to start it then. What does this return when you run it: `SELECT @@VERSION`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid it returns ok the version of the SQL server

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more specific. What does it return - _please post it_

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I have updated the question

Comment: OK, well it doesn't look like you have SQL Express, so I guess you just don't have rights to the SQL Agent

Comment: Your picture is truncated in "right" place, we cannot see edition. Please post here the result of  select SERVERPROPERTY('Edition')

Comment: @sepupic Standard Edition(64-bit)

Comment: Ok, please post here the result of exec sp_configure 'Agent XPs'

Comment: I get this exception:The configuration option 'Agent XPs' does not exist, or it may be an advanced option.

Comment: Of course it's advanced option...EXEC SP_CONFIGURE 'show advanced options',1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO

Comment: And then re-execute exec sp_configure 'Agent XPs'

Comment: I executed the commands. Now for 'exec sp_configure 'Agent XPs'' I get: Agent XPs: minimin:0, max:1, config_value:1, run_value:1

Comment: Ok, now please start your Agent from Services

Comment: I have started already, but I get the same error

Comment: Do you want to say that Agent is running but you get "the same error" SQL **Server Agent is not currently running** so it cannot be notified of this action ?

Comment: Yes, as you can see in the question (I have updated)